# Using C# to test internet connection on a remote Server

Tags: c#, connection, remote-server

Is it possible to write C# code to test internet connection on a remote server?

For example, if I were doing this using powerhsell, I would do this:

> Psexec \\MyWebServer ping www.google.com

Thanks

Comment: You mean, if you get an answer, the connection works? ^^;

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to check? Only internet connection or do you want to check a role (e.g. web server, database server)? If it's the latter, I wouldn't use ping for this. For example, let's say your server is running a database. Maybe the server itself is up and running and replies to ping requests, but the database server instance isn't running (correctly). By pinging the server, you can't determine if the server is doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: Hi Stefan,  I simply want to check internet connectivity on a remote web server.  this web server hosts a website that we access through our internal Intranet.... but you can make mock purchases on this webserver.  During those purchases, it will make a connection to an external credit card server via the internet.  If there is no internet, that task will fail.  I am creating a "health index" of that server that tracks many metrics.  Internet connectivity is 1 of many.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) and [PingReply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply.aspx) class  and include `System.Net.NetworkInformation` to check:

```
  Ping ping = new Ping();
  //PingReply reply= ping.Send("ip address");
  PingReply reply= ping.Send("www.google.com");


  if(reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
     // Connected 

       Console.WriteLine ("Address: {0}", reply.Address.ToString ());
       Console.WriteLine ("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
       Console.WriteLine ("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
       Console.WriteLine ("Don't fragment: {0}", reply.Options.DontFragment);
       Console.WriteLine ("Buffer size: {0}", reply.Buffer.Length);
    }
  else
    {
      Console.WriteLine (reply.Status);
    }
```

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hzczzed.aspx) for more details